# Matching dates between two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

In Pandas, I have two dataframes, both with dates.

One dataframe contains about 100000 dates and the other about 7000 dates.

How do I keep the dates in dataframe1 that matches the dates with dataframe2?

Comment: like `df1[df1['date'].isin(df2['date'])]`?

Comment: yes i tried that.  forward[forward['OPR_DATE'].isin(cash['OPR_DATE'])]
I forgot to mention that both the columns are dataframes.  they contain other columns as well such as prices etc.  but i need to match the dates.
However, it is still not working as checking the len(forward['OPR_DATE']) doesn't show me a reduced column at all.

Comment: so you're saying that doesn't work? that is strange, what version pandas, python and numpy are you running

Comment: python 2.7 i believe.  the latest version of pandas rolled with anaconda

Comment: What are the dtypes for those columns? Are they both datetime or strings?

Comment: yep both are dataframes.  forward contains dates and prices, cash contains dates and prices.  both are pandas dataframes obtained through csv parser.  I also converted the dates to datetime object

Comment: So what happens, do you get an empty dataframe? does this help: `forward[forward['OPR_DATE'].isin(cash['OPR_DATE'].unique())]`

Comment: ok i followed your recommendation.  lets see i put some test case:
len(forward['OPR_DATE']) = 116560
len(cash['opr_date']) = 7781
forward = forward[forward[opr_date'].isin(cash['oprdate']))
len(forward) = 98012 
cash = cash[cash['oprdate'].isin(forward['oprdate'])]
len(cash) = 7781
forward.head() gives me first date as 2012-09-09
cash.head() gives me first date as 2011-09-01.  why aren't the dates matching?

clearly the dataframe is being reduced.  but the first date is just not the same which is confusing to me...

Comment: i think with pandas dataframes, the isin works differently with dates...as opposed to a series. I tried another test case where i created a dataframe with 5 rows with dates and another dataframe with 3 rows with dates and it gave me all false using isin.  so clearly something is up wtih this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do an inner join operation. Since you only want data that exists in both dataframes.

[image]

Since you did not paste much about your code, I will provide a bit of a pseudo-example:

```
pd.merge(left=df_with_millions, left_on='date_column',
         right=df_with_seven_thousand, right_on='date_column')
```

You can read more about merging here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html